# disable rake db:test:prepare while using cucumber rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, ruby-on-rails-3.1, cucumber, bdd

i am using `bundle exec rake cucumber` to run my feature files but ***i need to customize it so that even after the cucumber tests are completed,my test database should persist because i would be dumping my remote production data into my local test database***. 
i also remove database-cleaner as by-default it cleans the test database..i tried to look into `cucumber.rake` and figured out these lines where it runs `test:prepare`

```
namespace :cucumber do
    Cucumber::Rake::Task.new({:ok => 'test:prepare'}, 'Run features that should pass') do |t|
      t.binary = vendored_cucumber_bin # If nil, the gem's binary is used.
      t.fork = true # You may get faster startup if you set this to false
      t.profile = 'default'
      t.rcov = true
    end
```

i want to disable deleting of my test database after my cucumber/rspec tests completes.is there any way because i tried searching but didnt got a good source.moreover i will be dumping data in test database..so the solution should work irrespective of the data in test database.

**my gemfile**

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'annotate'
  gem "factory_girl_rails", "~> 1.1.rc1"
  gem "factory_girl_generator", ">= 0.0.3"
  gem "rspec-rails", ">= 2.6.0"
  gem 'rr'
  gem 'ruby-debug'
  gem 'haml-rails'
  gem 'rcov'
  ##removed database cleaner as i want to persist test data always
  ##gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  ##cucumber,mysql added for test database ONLY
  gem 'cucumber-rails', :require => false
  gem 'mysql'
```

end

**cucumber.rake**

```
# IMPORTANT: This file is generated by cucumber-rails - edit at your own peril.
# It is recommended to regenerate this file in the future when you upgrade to a
# newer version of cucumber-rails. Consider adding your own code to a new file
# instead of editing this one. Cucumber will automatically load all features/**/*.rb
# files.


unless ARGV.any? {|a| a =~ /^gems/} # Don't load anything when running the gems:* tasks

vendored_cucumber_bin = Dir["#{Rails.root}/vendor/{gems,plugins}/cucumber*/bin/cucumber"].first
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.dirname(vendored_cucumber_bin) + '/../lib') unless vendored_cucumber_bin.nil?

begin
  require 'cucumber/rake/task'

  namespace :cucumber do
    Cucumber::Rake::Task.new({:ok => 'test:prepare'}, 'Run features that should pass') do |t|
      t.binary = vendored_cucumber_bin # If nil, the gem's binary is used.
      t.fork = true # You may get faster startup if you set this to false
      t.profile = 'default'
      t.rcov = true ##added to get coverage using rcov
    end

    Cucumber::Rake::Task.new({:wip => 'test:prepare'}, 'Run features that are being worked on') do |t|
      t.binary = vendored_cucumber_bin
      t.fork = true # You may get faster startup if you set this to false
      t.profile = 'wip'
      t.rcov = true ##added to get coverage using rcov
    end

    Cucumber::Rake::Task.new({:rerun => 'test:prepare'}, 'Record failing features and run only them if any exist') do |t|
      t.binary = vendored_cucumber_bin
      t.fork = true # You may get faster startup if you set this to false
      t.profile = 'rerun'
      t.rcov = true ##added to get coverage using rcov
    end

    desc 'Run all features'
    task :all => [:ok, :wip]

    task :statsetup do
      require 'rails/code_statistics'
      ::STATS_DIRECTORIES << %w(Cucumber\ features features) if File.exist?('features')
      ::CodeStatistics::TEST_TYPES << "Cucumber features" if File.exist?('features')
    end
  end
  desc 'Alias for cucumber:ok'
  task :cucumber => 'cucumber:ok'

  task :default => :cucumber

  task :features => :cucumber do
    STDERR.puts "*** The 'features' task is deprecated. See rake -T cucumber ***"
  end

  # In case we don't have the generic Rails test:prepare hook, append a no-op task that we can depend upon.
  task 'test:prepare' do
  end

  task :stats => 'cucumber:statsetup'
rescue LoadError
  desc 'cucumber rake task not available (cucumber not installed)'
  task :cucumber do
    abort 'Cucumber rake task is not available. Be sure to install cucumber as a gem or plugin'
  end
end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well i was not able to stop test:db:prepare but i was able to ***persist the test data*** even after running cucumber/rspec by setting this configuration to False in `env.rb`

```
Cucumber::Rails::World.use_transactional_fixtures = false
```

-------hope it helps  someone else as well.